# for loop only runs only for last row in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a simple issue with a for loop in R - I am trying to make it run for the entire dataset and it only runs for the last row. This is done with quite complex datasets which are both shapefiles and I am testing the intersection of the geometries. That is why I can't quite make a reproducible example here.

Nevertheless, this is my code:

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(data1)){
   #get intersections between data2 and data1 for specific years
     output = st_join(
     x    = data1[i, ],
     y    = data2[which(data2$year %in% data1$lag.year[i]:data1$year[i]), ],
     join = st_intersects
     )
     #Get area of intersections
      output = transform(output, 
                      inter_area = mapply(function(x, y) {
                                      as.numeric(sf::st_area(
                                           sf::st_intersection(x, y)
                                       ))}, x = geometry, y = geom_2))
        ## obtaining the proportion of area in data1 intersected by data2
  output = transform(output, prop_inter = inter_area/area)
  #get cycle-specific values
  output <- output%>%
    group_by(code, year.x)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(prop_inter = sum(prop_inter),
                   end_date= max(end_date),
           start_date= max(start_date))%>%
  ungroup()
  return(output)
}
```

As you can see I am testing the intersections of `data2` on `data1` and see which percentage of `data1` is intersected dependent on the values they take on `year` and `lag.year`. The issue is that when I run this it only returns the desidered outcome for the last row, instead of the entire `data1` object. I've tested all the different bits of code inside the loop separately and they all do as I want, but once I try to scale all of it up to the entire dataframe it just does it for the last row.

So I assume this must be some simple stupid mistake I am making for the loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep rewriting the output object; you may want to create a vector of length nrow(data) and assign the result to its i-th element. I don't think this relates to {sf} or GIS in general, it is more about how for loops and vectors work in R - consider this example:

```
for (i in 1:50) {
  
  output <- i # rewriting output object 50 times
  
}

print(output) # this will be a single element for last row (50)

output <- numeric(50)

for (i in 1:50) {
  
  output[i] <- i # storing result in a new element of output for each i
  
}

print(output) # this will be 1:50 as expected
```

You may want to consider something along these lines (hard to make certain without access to your data, but it should get you started).

```
result <- numeric(nrow(data1)) # init the vector

for(i in 1:nrow(data1)){
   #get intersections between data2 and data1 for specific years
     output = st_join(
     x    = data1[i, ],
     y    = data2[which(data2$year %in% data1$lag.year[i]:data1$year[i]), ],
     join = st_intersects
     )
     #Get area of intersections
      output = transform(output, 
                      inter_area = mapply(function(x, y) {
                                      as.numeric(sf::st_area(
                                           sf::st_intersection(x, y)
                                       ))}, x = geometry, y = geom_2))
        ## obtaining the proportion of area in data1 intersected by data2
  output = transform(output, prop_inter = inter_area/area)
  #get cycle-specific values

  result[i] <- output%>% # store in i-th element of result instead
    group_by(code, year.x)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(prop_inter = sum(prop_inter),
                   end_date= max(end_date),
           start_date= max(start_date))%>%
  ungroup()
#   return(output)  # no need for return unless you are in a function
}
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7756889/jindra-lacko Thank you so much - this is very useful! However, I'm now only getting one column in results "code", which is an id, and not the other columns I wanted to - year.x, prop_inter, end_date, and start_date, should I create several different columns within the object result beforehand?

Comment: I see... the last pipe returns 5 variables, these will not fit into a single vector. Try declaring the result object as a data.frame of 5 columns (code, year.x, prop_inter, end_date and start_date), each with relevant type - I can't tell from your code - and each of nrow(data1) length. Also change the final assignment from `result[i]` to `result[i, ]` as you are not dealing with an element of a vector, but with entire row of a tabular dataframe.

Comment: It worked! I had to create the results vector as a data frame and with all right object type for each column but once I did it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad it did!